# How to get the id (memory address) of dll-function?

Tags: c#, dll, memory-address, queryinterface, nvapi

I want to use a function from nvapi in C# "NvAPI_DRS_EnumProfiles".
I have to call QueryInterface(id) with the id of the function. 
Everything is working fine and i found the ids for the other functions i need on the web, 
but i can't find the id of this single function, and i don't know how to get it. 
I tried so many things and even a c-program which print me the memory-address didn't work.

My code looks something like this: http://www.drivenbynostalgia.com/files/SOP.cs

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 34):

NDA version of lib

```
_NvAPI_Initialize   150E828h
_NvAPI_Unload   0D22BDD7Eh
_NvAPI_GetErrorMessage  6C2D048Ch
_NvAPI_GetInterfaceVersionString    1053FA5h
_NvAPI_GetDisplayDriverVersion  0F951A4D1h
_NvAPI_SYS_GetDriverAndBranchVersion    2926AAADh
_NvAPI_EnumNvidiaDisplayHandle  9ABDD40Dh
_NvAPI_EnumNvidiaUnAttachedDisplayHandle    20DE9260h
_NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs 0E5AC921Fh
_NvAPI_EnumLogicalGPUs  48B3EA59h
_NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUsFromDisplay   34EF9506h
_NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUFromUnAttachedDisplay  5018ED61h
_NvAPI_CreateDisplayFromUnAttachedDisplay   63F9799Eh
_NvAPI_GetLogicalGPUFromDisplay 0EE1370CFh
_NvAPI_GetLogicalGPUFromPhysicalGPU 0ADD604D1h
_NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUsFromLogicalGPU    0AEA3FA32h
_NvAPI_GetAssociatedNvidiaDisplayHandle 35C29134h
_NvAPI_DISP_GetAssociatedUnAttachedNvidiaDisplayHandle  0A70503B2h
_NvAPI_GetAssociatedNvidiaDisplayName   22A78B05h
_NvAPI_GetUnAttachedAssociatedDisplayName   4888D790h
_NvAPI_EnableHWCursor   2863148Dh
_NvAPI_DisableHWCursor  0AB163097h
_NvAPI_GetVBlankCounter 67B5DB55h
_NvAPI_SetRefreshRateOverride   3092AC32h
_NvAPI_GetAssociatedDisplayOutputId 0D995937Eh
_NvAPI_GetDisplayPortInfo   0C64FF367h
_NvAPI_SetDisplayPort   0FA13E65Ah
_NvAPI_GetHDMISupportInfo   6AE16EC3h
_NvAPI_DISP_EnumHDMIStereoModes 0D2CCF5D6h
_NvAPI_GetInfoFrame 9734F1Dh
_NvAPI_SetInfoFrame 69C6F365h
_NvAPI_SetInfoFrameState    67EFD887h
_NvAPI_GetInfoFrameState    41511594h
_NvAPI_Disp_InfoFrameControl    6067AF3Fh
_NvAPI_Disp_ColorControl    92F9D80Dh
_NvAPI_DISP_GetVirtualModeData  3230D69Ah
_NvAPI_DISP_OverrideDisplayModeList 291BFF2h
_NvAPI_GetDisplayDriverMemoryInfo   774AA982h
_NvAPI_GetDriverMemoryInfo  2DC95125h
_NvAPI_GetDVCInfo   4085DE45h
_NvAPI_SetDVCLevel  172409B4h
_NvAPI_GetDVCInfoEx 0E45002Dh
_NvAPI_SetDVCLevelEx    4A82C2B1h
_NvAPI_GetHUEInfo   95B64341h
_NvAPI_SetHUEAngle  0F5A0F22Ch
_NvAPI_GetImageSharpeningInfo   9FB063DFh
_NvAPI_SetImageSharpeningLevel  3FC9A59Ch
_NvAPI_D3D_GetCurrentSLIState   4B708B54h
_NvAPI_D3D9_RegisterResource    0A064BDFCh
_NvAPI_D3D9_UnregisterResource  0BB2B17AAh
_NvAPI_D3D9_AliasSurfaceAsTexture   0E5CEAE41h
_NvAPI_D3D9_StretchRectEx   22DE03AAh
_NvAPI_D3D9_ClearRT 332D3942h
_NvAPI_D3D_CreateQuery  5D19BCA4h
_NvAPI_D3D_DestroyQuery 0C8FF7258h
_NvAPI_D3D_Query_Begin  0E5A9AAE0h
_NvAPI_D3D_Query_End    2AC084FAh
_NvAPI_D3D_Query_GetData    0F8B53C69h
_NvAPI_D3D_Query_GetDataSize    0F2A54796h
_NvAPI_D3D_Query_GetType    4ACEEAF7h
_NvAPI_D3D_RegisterApp  0D44D3C4Eh
_NvAPI_D3D9_CreatePathContextNV 0A342F682h
_NvAPI_D3D9_DestroyPathContextNV    667C2929h
_NvAPI_D3D9_CreatePathNV    71329DF3h
_NvAPI_D3D9_DeletePathNV    73E0019Ah
_NvAPI_D3D9_PathVerticesNV  0C23DF926h
_NvAPI_D3D9_PathParameterfNV    0F7FF00C1h
_NvAPI_D3D9_PathParameteriNV    0FC31236Ch
_NvAPI_D3D9_PathMatrixNV    0D2F6C499h
_NvAPI_D3D9_PathDepthNV 0FCB16330h
_NvAPI_D3D9_PathClearDepthNV    157E45C4h
_NvAPI_D3D9_PathEnableDepthTestNV   0E99BA7F3h
_NvAPI_D3D9_PathEnableColorWriteNV  3E2804A2h
_NvAPI_D3D9_DrawPathNV  13199B3Dh
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetSurfaceHandle    0F2DD3F2h
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetOverlaySurfaceHandles    6800F5FCh
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetTextureHandle    0C7985ED5h
_NvAPI_D3D9_GpuSyncGetHandleSize    80C9FD3Bh
_NvAPI_D3D9_GpuSyncInit 6D6FDAD4h
_NvAPI_D3D9_GpuSyncEnd  754033F0h
_NvAPI_D3D9_GpuSyncMapTexBuffer 0CDE4A28Ah
_NvAPI_D3D9_GpuSyncMapSurfaceBuffer 2AB714ABh
_NvAPI_D3D9_GpuSyncMapVertexBuffer  0DBC803ECh
_NvAPI_D3D9_GpuSyncMapIndexBuffer   12EE68F2h
_NvAPI_D3D9_SetPitchSurfaceCreation 18CDF365h
_NvAPI_D3D9_GpuSyncAcquire  0D00B8317h
_NvAPI_D3D9_GpuSyncRelease  3D7A86BBh
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetCurrentRenderTargetHandle    22CAD61h
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetCurrentZBufferHandle 0B380F218h
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetIndexBufferHandle    0FC5A155Bh
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetVertexBufferHandle   72B19155h
_NvAPI_D3D9_CreateTexture   0D5E13573h
_NvAPI_D3D9_AliasPrimaryAsTexture   13C7112Eh
_NvAPI_D3D9_PresentSurfaceToDesktop 0F7029C5h
_NvAPI_D3D9_CreateVideoBegin    84C9D553h
_NvAPI_D3D9_CreateVideoEnd  0B476BF61h
_NvAPI_D3D9_CreateVideo 89FFD9A3h
_NvAPI_D3D9_FreeVideo   3111BED1h
_NvAPI_D3D9_PresentVideo    5CF7F862h
_NvAPI_D3D9_VideoSetStereoInfo  0B852F4DBh
_NvAPI_D3D9_SetGamutData    2BBDA32Eh
_NvAPI_D3D9_SetSurfaceCreationLayout    5609B86Ah
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetVideoCapabilities    3D596B93h
_NvAPI_D3D9_QueryVideoInfo  1E6634B3h
_NvAPI_D3D9_AliasPrimaryFromDevice  7C20C5BEh
_NvAPI_D3D9_SetResourceHint 905F5C27h
_NvAPI_D3D9_Lock    6317345Ch
_NvAPI_D3D9_Unlock  0C182027Eh
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetVideoState   0A4527BF8h
_NvAPI_D3D9_SetVideoState   0BD4BC56Fh
_NvAPI_D3D9_EnumVideoFeatures   1DB7C52Ch
_NvAPI_D3D9_GetSLIInfo  694BFF4Dh
_NvAPI_D3D9_SetSLIMode  0BFDC062Ch
_NvAPI_D3D9_QueryAAOverrideMode 0DDF5643Ch
_NvAPI_D3D9_VideoSurfaceEncryptionControl   9D2509EFh
_NvAPI_D3D9_DMA 962B8AF6h
_NvAPI_D3D9_EnableStereo    492A6954h
_NvAPI_D3D9_StretchRect 0AEAECD41h
_NvAPI_D3D9_CreateRenderTarget  0B3827C8h
_NvAPI_D3D9_NVFBC_GetStatus 0BD3EB475h
_NvAPI_D3D9_IFR_SetUpTargetBufferToSys  55255D05h
_NvAPI_D3D9_GPUBasedCPUSleep    0D504DDA7h
_NvAPI_D3D9_IFR_TransferRenderTarget    0AB7C2DCh
_NvAPI_D3D9_IFR_SetUpTargetBufferToNV12BLVideoSurface   0CFC92C15h
_NvAPI_D3D9_IFR_TransferRenderTargetToNV12BLVideoSurface    5FE72F64h
_NvAPI_D3D10_AliasPrimaryAsTexture  8AAC133Dh
_NvAPI_D3D10_SetPrimaryFlipChainCallbacks   73EB9329h
_NvAPI_D3D10_ProcessCallbacks   0AE9C2019h
_NvAPI_D3D10_GetRenderedCursorAsBitmap  0CAC3CE5Dh
_NvAPI_D3D10_BeginShareResource 35233210h
_NvAPI_D3D10_BeginShareResourceEx   0EF303A9Dh
_NvAPI_D3D10_EndShareResource   0E9C5853h
_NvAPI_D3D10_SetDepthBoundsTest 4EADF5D2h
_NvAPI_D3D10_CreateDevice   2DE11D61h
_NvAPI_D3D10_CreateDeviceAndSwapChain   5B803DAFh
_NvAPI_D3D11_CreateDevice   6A16D3A0h
_NvAPI_D3D11_CreateDeviceAndSwapChain   0BB939EE5h
_NvAPI_D3D11_BeginShareResource 121BDC6h
_NvAPI_D3D11_EndShareResource   8FFB8E26h
_NvAPI_D3D11_SetDepthBoundsTest 7AAF7A04h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetShaderPipeCount   63E2F56Fh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetShaderSubPipeCount    0BE17923h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPartitionCount    86F05D7Ah
_NvAPI_GPU_GetMemPartitionMask  329D77CDh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetTPCMask   4A35DF54h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetSMMask    0EB7AF173h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetTotalTPCCount 4E2F76A8h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetTotalSMCount  0AE5FBCFEh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetTotalSPCount  0B6D62591h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetGpuCoreCount  0C7026A87h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetAllOutputs    7D554F8Eh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedOutputs  1730BFC9h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedSLIOutputs   680DE09h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds   78DBA2h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds 785210A2h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedOutputsWithLidState  0CF8CAF39h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedSLIOutputsWithLidState   96043CC7h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetSystemType    0BAAABFCCh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetActiveOutputs 0E3E89B6Fh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetEDID  37D32E69h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetEDID  0E83D6456h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetOutputType    40A505E4h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetDeviceDisplayMode 0D2277E3Ah
_NvAPI_GPU_GetFlatPanelInfo 36CFF969h
_NvAPI_GPU_ValidateOutputCombination    34C9C2D4h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectorInfo 4ECA2C10h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetFullName  0CEEE8E9Fh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPCIIdentifiers    2DDFB66Eh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetGPUType   0C33BAEB1h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetBusType   1BB18724h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetBusId 1BE0B8E5h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetBusSlotId 2A0A350Fh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetIRQ   0E4715417h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetVbiosRevision 0ACC3DA0Ah
_NvAPI_GPU_GetVbiosOEMRevision  2D43FB31h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetVbiosVersionString    0A561FD7Dh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetAGPAperture   6E042794h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetCurrentAGPRate    0C74925A0h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetCurrentPCIEDownstreamWidth    0D048C3B1h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPhysicalFrameBufferSize   46FBEB03h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetVirtualFrameBufferSize    5A04B644h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetQuadroStatus  0E332FA47h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetBoardInfo 22D54523h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetRamType   57F7CAACh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetFBWidthAndLocation    11104158h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetAllClockFrequencies   0DCB616C3h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPerfClocks    1EA54A3Bh
_NvAPI_GPU_SetPerfClocks    7BCF4ACh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetCoolerSettings    0DA141340h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetCoolerLevels  891FA0AEh
_NvAPI_GPU_RestoreCoolerSettings    8F6ED0FBh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetCoolerPolicyTable 518A32Ch
_NvAPI_GPU_SetCoolerPolicyTable 987947CDh
_NvAPI_GPU_RestoreCoolerPolicyTable 0D8C4FE63h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPstatesInfo   0BA94C56Eh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPstatesInfoEx 843C0256h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetPstatesInfo   0CDF27911h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPstates20 6FF81213h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetPstates20 0F4DAE6Bh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetCurrentPstate 927DA4F6h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPstateClientLimits    88C82104h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetPstateClientLimits    0FDFC7D49h
_NvAPI_GPU_EnableOverclockedPstates 0B23B70EEh
_NvAPI_GPU_EnableDynamicPstates 0FA579A0Fh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetDynamicPstatesInfoEx  60DED2EDh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetVoltages  7D656244h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetThermalSettings   0E3640A56h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetDitherControl 0DF0DFCDDh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetDitherControl 932AC8FBh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetColorSpaceConversion  8159E87Ah
_NvAPI_GPU_SetColorSpaceConversion  0FCABD23Ah
_NvAPI_GetTVOutputInfo  30C805D5h
_NvAPI_GetTVEncoderControls 5757474Ah
_NvAPI_SetTVEncoderControls 0CA36A3ABh
_NvAPI_GetTVOutputBorderColor   6DFD1C8Ch
_NvAPI_SetTVOutputBorderColor   0AED02700h
_NvAPI_GetDisplayPosition   6BB1EE5Dh
_NvAPI_SetDisplayPosition   57D9060Fh
_NvAPI_GetValidGpuTopologies    5DFAB48Ah
_NvAPI_GetInvalidGpuTopologies  15658BE6h
_NvAPI_SetGpuTopologies 25201F3Dh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPerGpuTopologyStatus  0A81F8992h
_NvAPI_SYS_GetChipSetTopologyStatus 8A50F126h
_NvAPI_GPU_Get_DisplayPort_DongleInfo   76A70E8Dh
_NvAPI_I2CRead  2FDE12C5h
_NvAPI_I2CWrite 0E812EB07h
_NvAPI_I2CWriteEx   283AC65Ah
_NvAPI_I2CReadEx    4D7B0709h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPowerMizerInfo    76BFA16Bh
_NvAPI_GPU_SetPowerMizerInfo    50016C78h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetVoltageDomainsStatus  0C16C7E2Ch
_NvAPI_GPU_ClientPowerTopologyGetInfo   0A4DFD3F2h
_NvAPI_GPU_ClientPowerTopologyGetStatus 0EDCF624Eh
_NvAPI_GPU_ClientPowerPoliciesGetInfo   34206D86h
_NvAPI_GPU_ClientPowerPoliciesGetStatus 70916171h
_NvAPI_GPU_ClientPowerPoliciesSetStatus 0AD95F5EDh
_NvAPI_GPU_WorkstationFeatureSetup  6C1F3FE4h
_NvAPI_SYS_GetChipSetInfo   53DABBCAh
_NvAPI_SYS_GetLidAndDockInfo    0CDA14D8Ah
_NvAPI_OGL_ExpertModeSet    3805EF7Ah
_NvAPI_OGL_ExpertModeGet    22ED9516h
_NvAPI_OGL_ExpertModeDefaultsSet    0B47A657Eh
_NvAPI_OGL_ExpertModeDefaultsGet    0AE921F12h
_NvAPI_SetDisplaySettings   0E04F3D86h
_NvAPI_GetDisplaySettings   0DC27D5D4h
_NvAPI_GetTiming    0AFC4833Eh
_NvAPI_DISP_GetMonitorCapabilities  3B05C7E1h
_NvAPI_EnumCustomDisplay    42892957h
_NvAPI_TryCustomDisplay 0BF6C1762h
_NvAPI_RevertCustomDisplayTrial 854BA405h
_NvAPI_DeleteCustomDisplay  0E7CB998Dh
_NvAPI_SaveCustomDisplay    0A9062C78h
_NvAPI_QueryUnderscanCap    61D7B624h
_NvAPI_EnumUnderscanConfig  4144111Ah
_NvAPI_DeleteUnderscanConfig    0F98854C8h
_NvAPI_SetUnderscanConfig   3EFADA1Dh
_NvAPI_GetDisplayFeatureConfig  8E985CCDh
_NvAPI_SetDisplayFeatureConfig  0F36A668Dh
_NvAPI_GetDisplayFeatureConfigDefaults  0F5F4D01h
_NvAPI_SetView  957D7B6h
_NvAPI_GetView  0D6B99D89h
_NvAPI_SetViewEx    6B89E68h
_NvAPI_GetViewEx    0DBBC0AF4h
_NvAPI_GetSupportedViews    66FB7FC0h
_NvAPI_GetHDCPLinkParameters    0B3BB0772h
_NvAPI_Disp_DpAuxChannelControl 8EB56969h
_NvAPI_SetHybridMode    0FB22D656h
_NvAPI_GetHybridMode    0E23B68C1h
_NvAPI_Coproc_GetCoprocStatus   1EFC3957h
_NvAPI_Coproc_SetCoprocInfoFlagsEx  0F4C863ACh
_NvAPI_Coproc_GetCoprocInfoFlagsEx  69A9874Dh
_NvAPI_Coproc_NotifyCoprocPowerState    0CADCB956h
_NvAPI_Coproc_GetApplicationCoprocInfo  79232685h
_NvAPI_GetVideoState    1C5659CDh
_NvAPI_SetVideoState    54FE75Ah
_NvAPI_SetFrameRateNotify   18919887h
_NvAPI_SetPVExtName 4FEEB498h
_NvAPI_GetPVExtName 2F5B08E0h
_NvAPI_SetPVExtProfile  8354A8F4h
_NvAPI_GetPVExtProfile  1B1B9A16h
_NvAPI_VideoSetStereoInfo   97063269h
_NvAPI_VideoGetStereoInfo   8E1F8CFEh
_NvAPI_Mosaic_GetSupportedTopoInfo  0FDB63C81h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_GetTopoGroup  0CB89381Dh
_NvAPI_Mosaic_GetOverlapLimits  989685F0h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_SetCurrentTopo    9B542831h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_GetCurrentTopo    0EC32944Eh
_NvAPI_Mosaic_EnableCurrentTopo 5F1AA66Ch
_NvAPI_Mosaic_SetGridTopology   3F113C77h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_GetMosaicCapabilities 0DA97071Eh
_NvAPI_Mosaic_GetDisplayCapabilities    0D58026B9h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_EnumGridTopologies    0A3C55220h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_GetDisplayViewportsByResolution   0DC6DC8D3h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_GetMosaicViewports    7EBA036h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_SetDisplayGrids   4D959A89h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_ValidateDisplayGridsWithSLI   1ECFD263h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_ValidateDisplayGrids  0CF43903Dh
_NvAPI_Mosaic_EnumDisplayModes  78DB97D7h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_ChooseGpuTopologies   0B033B140h
_NvAPI_Mosaic_EnumDisplayGrids  0DF2887AFh
_NvAPI_GetSupportedMosaicTopologies 410B5C25h
_NvAPI_GetCurrentMosaicTopology 0F60852BDh
_NvAPI_SetCurrentMosaicTopology 0D54B8989h
_NvAPI_EnableCurrentMosaicTopology  74073CC9h
_NvAPI_QueryNonMigratableApps   0BB9EF1C3h
_NvAPI_GPU_QueryActiveApps  65B1C5F5h
_NvAPI_Hybrid_QueryUnblockedNonMigratableApps   5F35BCB5h
_NvAPI_Hybrid_QueryBlockedMigratableApps    0F4C2F8CCh
_NvAPI_Hybrid_SetAppMigrationState  0FA0B9A59h
_NvAPI_Hybrid_IsAppMigrationStateChangeable 584CB0B6h
_NvAPI_GPU_GPIOQueryLegalPins   0FAB69565h
_NvAPI_GPU_GPIOReadFromPin  0F5E10439h
_NvAPI_GPU_GPIOWriteToPin   0F3B11E68h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetHDCPSupportStatus 0F089EEF5h
_NvAPI_SetTopologyFocusDisplayAndView   0A8064F9h
_NvAPI_Stereo_CreateConfigurationProfileRegistryKey 0BE7692ECh
_NvAPI_Stereo_DeleteConfigurationProfileRegistryKey 0F117B834h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetConfigurationProfileValue  24409F48h
_NvAPI_Stereo_DeleteConfigurationProfileValue   49BCEECFh
_NvAPI_Stereo_Enable    239C4545h
_NvAPI_Stereo_Disable   2EC50C2Bh
_NvAPI_Stereo_IsEnabled 348FF8E1h
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetStereoCaps 0DFC063B7h
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetStereoSupport  296C434Dh
_NvAPI_Stereo_CreateHandleFromIUnknown  0AC7E37F4h
_NvAPI_Stereo_DestroyHandle 3A153134h
_NvAPI_Stereo_Activate  0F6A1AD68h
_NvAPI_Stereo_Deactivate    2D68DE96h
_NvAPI_Stereo_IsActivated   1FB0BC30h
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetSeparation 451F2134h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetSeparation 5C069FA3h
_NvAPI_Stereo_DecreaseSeparation    0DA044458h
_NvAPI_Stereo_IncreaseSeparation    0C9A8ECECh
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetConvergence    4AB00934h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetConvergence    3DD6B54Bh
_NvAPI_Stereo_DecreaseConvergence   4C87E317h
_NvAPI_Stereo_IncreaseConvergence   0A17DAABEh
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetFrustumAdjustMode  0E6839B43h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetFrustumAdjustMode  7BE27FA2h
_NvAPI_Stereo_CaptureJpegImage  932CB140h
_NvAPI_Stereo_CapturePngImage   8B7E99B5h
_NvAPI_Stereo_ReverseStereoBlitControl  3CD58F89h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetNotificationMessage    6B9B409Eh
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetActiveEye  96EEA9F8h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetDriverMode 5E8F0BECh
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetEyeSeparation  0CE653127h
_NvAPI_Stereo_IsWindowedModeSupported   40C8ED5Eh
_NvAPI_Stereo_AppHandShake  8C610BDAh
_NvAPI_Stereo_HandShake_Trigger_Activation  0B30CD1A7h
_NvAPI_Stereo_HandShake_Message_Control 315E0EF0h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetSurfaceCreationMode    0F5DCFCBAh
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetSurfaceCreationMode    36F1C736h
_NvAPI_Stereo_Debug_WasLastDrawStereoized   0ED4416C5h
_NvAPI_Stereo_ForceToScreenDepth    2D495758h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetVertexShaderConstantF  416C07B3h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetVertexShaderConstantB  5268716Fh
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetVertexShaderConstantI  7923BA0Eh
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetVertexShaderConstantF  622FDC87h
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetVertexShaderConstantB  712BAA5Bh
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetVertexShaderConstantI  5A60613Ah
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetPixelShaderConstantF   0A9657F32h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetPixelShaderConstantB   0BA6109EEh
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetPixelShaderConstantI   912AC28Fh
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetPixelShaderConstantF   0D4974572h
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetPixelShaderConstantB   0C79333AEh
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetPixelShaderConstantI   0ECD8F8CFh
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetDefaultProfile 44F0ECD1h
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetDefaultProfile 624E21C2h
_NvAPI_Stereo_Is3DCursorSupported   0D7C9EC09h
_NvAPI_Stereo_GetCursorSeparation   72162B35h
_NvAPI_Stereo_SetCursorSeparation   0FBC08FC1h
_NvAPI_VIO_GetCapabilities  1DC91303h
_NvAPI_VIO_Open 44EE4841h
_NvAPI_VIO_Close    0D01BD237h
_NvAPI_VIO_Status   0E6CE4F1h
_NvAPI_VIO_SyncFormatDetect 118D48A3h
_NvAPI_VIO_GetConfig    0D34A789Bh
_NvAPI_VIO_SetConfig    0E4EEC07h
_NvAPI_VIO_SetCSC   0A1EC8D74h
_NvAPI_VIO_GetCSC   7B0D72A3h
_NvAPI_VIO_SetGamma 964BF452h
_NvAPI_VIO_GetGamma 51D53D06h
_NvAPI_VIO_SetSyncDelay 2697A8D1h
_NvAPI_VIO_GetSyncDelay 462214A9h
_NvAPI_VIO_GetPCIInfo   0B981D935h
_NvAPI_VIO_IsRunning    96BD040Eh
_NvAPI_VIO_Start    0CDE8E1A3h
_NvAPI_VIO_Stop 6BA2A5D6h
_NvAPI_VIO_IsFrameLockModeCompatible    7BF0A94Dh
_NvAPI_VIO_EnumDevices  0FD7C5557h
_NvAPI_VIO_QueryTopology    869534E2h
_NvAPI_VIO_EnumSignalFormats    0EAD72FE4h
_NvAPI_VIO_EnumDataFormats  221FA8E8h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetTachReading   5F608315h
_NvAPI_3D_GetProperty   8061A4B1h
_NvAPI_3D_SetProperty   0C9175E8Dh
_NvAPI_3D_GetPropertyRange  0B85DE27Ch
_NvAPI_GPS_GetPowerSteeringStatus   540EE82Eh
_NvAPI_GPS_SetPowerSteeringStatus   9723D3A2h
_NvAPI_GPS_SetVPStateCap    68888EB4h
_NvAPI_GPS_GetVPStateCap    71913023h
_NvAPI_GPS_GetThermalLimit  583113EDh
_NvAPI_GPS_SetThermalLimit  0C07E210Fh
_NvAPI_GPS_GetPerfSensors   271C1109h
_NvAPI_SYS_GetDisplayIdFromGpuAndOutputId   8F2BAB4h
_NvAPI_SYS_GetGpuAndOutputIdFromDisplayId   112BA1A5h
_NvAPI_DISP_GetDisplayIdByDisplayName   0AE457190h
_NvAPI_DISP_GetGDIPrimaryDisplayId  1E9D8A31h
_NvAPI_DISP_GetDisplayConfig    11ABCCF8h
_NvAPI_DISP_SetDisplayConfig    5D8CF8DEh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPixelClockRange   66AF10B7h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetPixelClockRange   5AC7F8E5h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetECCStatusInfo 0CA1DDAF3h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetECCErrorInfo  0C71F85A6h
_NvAPI_GPU_ResetECCErrorInfo    0C02EEC20h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetECCConfigurationInfo  77A796F3h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetECCConfiguration  1CF639D9h
_NvAPI_D3D1x_CreateSwapChain    1BC21B66h
_NvAPI_D3D9_CreateSwapChain 1A131E09h
_NvAPI_D3D_SetFPSIndicatorState 0A776E8DBh
_NvAPI_D3D9_Present 5650BEBh
_NvAPI_D3D9_QueryFrameCount 9083E53Ah
_NvAPI_D3D9_ResetFrameCount 0FA6A0675h
_NvAPI_D3D9_QueryMaxSwapGroup   5995410Dh
_NvAPI_D3D9_QuerySwapGroup  0EBA4D232h
_NvAPI_D3D9_JoinSwapGroup   7D44BB54h
_NvAPI_D3D9_BindSwapBarrier 9C39C246h
_NvAPI_D3D1x_Present    3B845A1h
_NvAPI_D3D1x_QueryFrameCount    9152E055h
_NvAPI_D3D1x_ResetFrameCount    0FBBB031Ah
_NvAPI_D3D1x_QueryMaxSwapGroup  9BB9D68Fh
_NvAPI_D3D1x_QuerySwapGroup 407F67AAh
_NvAPI_D3D1x_JoinSwapGroup  14610CD7h
_NvAPI_D3D1x_BindSwapBarrier    9DE8C729h
_NvAPI_SYS_VenturaGetState  0CB7C208Dh
_NvAPI_SYS_VenturaSetState  0CE2E9D9h
_NvAPI_SYS_VenturaGetCoolingBudget  0C9D86E33h
_NvAPI_SYS_VenturaSetCoolingBudget  85FF5A15h
_NvAPI_SYS_VenturaGetPowerReading   63685979h
_NvAPI_DISP_GetDisplayBlankingState 63E5D8DBh
_NvAPI_DISP_SetDisplayBlankingState 1E17E29Bh
_NvAPI_DRS_CreateSession    694D52Eh
_NvAPI_DRS_DestroySession   0DAD9CFF8h
_NvAPI_DRS_LoadSettings 375DBD6Bh
_NvAPI_DRS_SaveSettings 0FCBC7E14h
_NvAPI_DRS_LoadSettingsFromFile 0D3EDE889h
_NvAPI_DRS_SaveSettingsToFile   2BE25DF8h
_NvAPI_DRS_CreateProfile    0CC176068h
_NvAPI_DRS_DeleteProfile    17093206h
_NvAPI_DRS_SetCurrentGlobalProfile  1C89C5DFh
_NvAPI_DRS_GetCurrentGlobalProfile  617BFF9Fh
_NvAPI_DRS_GetProfileInfo   61CD6FD6h
_NvAPI_DRS_SetProfileInfo   16ABD3A9h
_NvAPI_DRS_FindProfileByName    7E4A9A0Bh
_NvAPI_DRS_EnumProfiles 0BC371EE0h
_NvAPI_DRS_GetNumProfiles   1DAE4FBCh
_NvAPI_DRS_CreateApplication    4347A9DEh
_NvAPI_DRS_DeleteApplicationEx  0C5EA85A1h
_NvAPI_DRS_DeleteApplication    2C694BC6h
_NvAPI_DRS_GetApplicationInfo   0ED1F8C69h
_NvAPI_DRS_EnumApplications 7FA2173Ah
_NvAPI_DRS_FindApplicationByName    0EEE566B2h
_NvAPI_DRS_SetSetting   577DD202h
_NvAPI_DRS_GetSetting   73BF8338h
_NvAPI_DRS_EnumSettings 0AE3039DAh
_NvAPI_DRS_EnumAvailableSettingIds  0F020614Ah
_NvAPI_DRS_EnumAvailableSettingValues   2EC39F90h
_NvAPI_DRS_GetSettingIdFromName 0CB7309CDh
_NvAPI_DRS_GetSettingNameFromId 0D61CBE6Eh
_NvAPI_DRS_DeleteProfileSetting 0E4A26362h
_NvAPI_DRS_RestoreAllDefaults   5927B094h
_NvAPI_DRS_RestoreProfileDefault    0FA5F6134h
_NvAPI_DRS_RestoreProfileDefaultSetting 53F0381Eh
_NvAPI_DRS_GetBaseProfile   0DA8466A0h
_NvAPI_Event_RegisterCallback   0E6DBEA69h
_NvAPI_Event_UnregisterCallback 0DE1F9B45h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetCurrentThermalLevel   0D2488B79h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetCurrentFanSpeedLevel  0BD71F0C9h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetScanoutIntensity  0A57457A4h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetScanoutWarping    0B34BAB4Fh
_NvAPI_GPU_GetScanoutConfiguration  6A9F5B63h
_NvAPI_DISP_SetHCloneTopology   61041C24h
_NvAPI_DISP_GetHCloneTopology   47BAD137h
_NvAPI_DISP_ValidateHCloneTopology  5F4C2664h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetPerfDecreaseInfo  7F7F4600h
_NvAPI_GPU_QueryIlluminationSupport 0A629DA31h
_NvAPI_GPU_GetIllumination  9A1B9365h
_NvAPI_GPU_SetIllumination  254A187h
_NvAPI_D3D1x_IFR_SetUpTargetBufferToSys 473F7828h
_NvAPI_D3D1x_IFR_TransferRenderTarget   9FBAE4EBh
```

Comment: Holy s***! How did you enumerate these?

Comment: I note that `dumpbin /disasm | grep -E "(^NvAPI_|mov         *ecx,[0-9A-Z]*h$)"` shows different ordinals for some of these functions on my machine.  (Not NDA).

Answer (score 12):

There is a way to get those IDs. I disassembled the nvapi.lib with the VS dumpbin tool and analysed the result.
Here is a full list of current functions and their IDs:

```
          NvAPI_GetUnAttachedAssociatedDisplayName  -  4888D790
                              NvAPI_Stereo_Disable  -  2EC50C2B
                       NvAPI_GPU_GetPCIIdentifiers  -  2DDFB66E
                         NvAPI_GPU_GetECCErrorInfo  -  C71F85A6
                       NvAPI_Disp_InfoFrameControl  -  6067AF3F
                       NvAPI_Mosaic_GetCurrentTopo  -  EC32944E
                                      NvAPI_Unload  -  D22BDD7E
                 NvAPI_EnableCurrentMosaicTopology  -  74073CC9
                          NvAPI_DRS_GetNumProfiles  -  1DAE4FBC
                    NvAPI_DRS_LoadSettingsFromFile  -  D3EDE889
                 NvAPI_Stereo_SetFrustumAdjustMode  -  7BE27FA2
                       NvAPI_Mosaic_SetCurrentTopo  -  9B542831
                      NvAPI_DRS_GetApplicationInfo  -  ED1F8C69
                             NvAPI_Stereo_Activate  -  F6A1AD68
                 NvAPI_Stereo_GetFrustumAdjustMode  -  E6839B43
                    NvAPI_D3D_SetFPSIndicatorState  -  A776E8DB
                NvAPI_GetLogicalGPUFromPhysicalGPU  -  ADD604D1
              NvAPI_GetAssociatedNvidiaDisplayName  -  22A78B05
                                   NvAPI_GetViewEx  -  DBBC0AF4
                      NvAPI_Stereo_CapturePngImage  -  8B7E99B5
               NvAPI_Stereo_GetSurfaceCreationMode  -  36F1C736
                                 NvAPI_GPU_GetEDID  -  37D32E69
NvAPI_Stereo_CreateConfigurationProfileRegistryKey  -  BE7692EC
                                  NvAPI_VIO_Status  -  0E6CE4F1
                 NvAPI_DRS_GetCurrentGlobalProfile  -  617BFF9F
                              NvAPI_VIO_GetPCIInfo  -  B981D935
                NvAPI_GetSupportedMosaicTopologies  -  410B5C25
                            NvAPI_VIO_SetSyncDelay  -  2697A8D1
                         NvAPI_GPU_SetIllumination  -  0254A187
                                NvAPI_VIO_GetGamma  -  51D53D06
                           NvAPI_Disp_ColorControl  -  92F9D80D
                           NvAPI_GetSupportedViews  -  66FB7FC0
                            NvAPI_DRS_LoadSettings  -  375DBD6B
                       NvAPI_DRS_CreateApplication  -  4347A9DE
                             NvAPI_EnumLogicalGPUs  -  48B3EA59
               NvAPI_Stereo_SetSurfaceCreationMode  -  F5DCFCBA
                       NvAPI_DISP_GetDisplayConfig  -  11ABCCF8
                    NvAPI_GetCurrentMosaicTopology  -  F60852BD
                             NvAPI_DisableHWCursor  -  AB163097
                  NvAPI_D3D9_AliasSurfaceAsTexture  -  E5CEAE41
                            NvAPI_GPU_GetBusSlotId  -  2A0A350F
                          NvAPI_GPU_GetTachReading  -  5F608315
                        NvAPI_Stereo_SetSeparation  -  5C069FA3
                        NvAPI_GPU_GetECCStatusInfo  -  CA1DDAF3
               NvAPI_VIO_IsFrameLockModeCompatible  -  7BF0A94D
                     NvAPI_Mosaic_EnumDisplayGrids  -  DF2887AF
                       NvAPI_DISP_SetDisplayConfig  -  5D8CF8DE
                 NvAPI_DRS_EnumAvailableSettingIds  -  F020614A
                               NvAPI_VIO_SetConfig  -  0E4EEC07
                     NvAPI_GPU_GetPerfDecreaseInfo  -  7F7F4600
                       NvAPI_SYS_GetLidAndDockInfo  -  CDA14D8A
                            NvAPI_GPU_GetPstates20  -  6FF81213
                           NvAPI_GPU_GetAllOutputs  -  7D554F8E
                  NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedSLIOutputs  -  0680DE09
                               NvAPI_VIO_IsRunning  -  96BD040E
                                  NvAPI_Initialize  -  0150E828
                                   NvAPI_VIO_Close  -  D01BD237
                     NvAPI_Stereo_GetStereoSupport  -  296C434D
                              NvAPI_GPU_GetGPUType  -  C33BAEB1
                     NvAPI_Stereo_CaptureJpegImage  -  932CB140
                          NvAPI_DRS_GetProfileInfo  -  61CD6FD6
         NvAPI_Stereo_SetConfigurationProfileValue  -  24409F48
                        NvAPI_VIO_SyncFormatDetect  -  118D48A3
                         NvAPI_VIO_GetCapabilities  -  1DC91303
                       NvAPI_GPU_GetCurrentAGPRate  -  C74925A0
                                    NvAPI_I2CWrite  -  E812EB07
                        NvAPI_Stereo_GetSeparation  -  451F2134
                        NvAPI_GPU_GetPstatesInfoEx  -  843C0256
                 NvAPI_DRS_SetCurrentGlobalProfile  -  1C89C5DF
                         NvAPI_Mosaic_GetTopoGroup  -  CB89381D
           NvAPI_GPU_GetCurrentPCIEDownstreamWidth  -  D048C3B1
                       NvAPI_D3D9_RegisterResource  -  A064BDFC
            NvAPI_DRS_RestoreProfileDefaultSetting  -  53F0381E
                            NvAPI_VIO_GetSyncDelay  -  462214A9
                     NvAPI_GPU_GetVbiosOEMRevision  -  2D43FB31
                            NvAPI_GetVBlankCounter  -  67B5DB55
                     NvAPI_GetDisplayDriverVersion  -  F951A4D1
                            NvAPI_DRS_EnumSettings  -  AE3039DA
                NvAPI_GPU_QueryIlluminationSupport  -  A629DA31
                    NvAPI_GetLogicalGPUFromDisplay  -  EE1370CF
                        NvAPI_DRS_EnumApplications  -  7FA2173A
                    NvAPI_Mosaic_EnableCurrentTopo  -  5F1AA66C
                          NvAPI_Stereo_IsActivated  -  1FB0BC30
                                    NvAPI_VIO_Stop  -  6BA2A5D6
                          NvAPI_SYS_GetChipSetInfo  -  53DABBCA
                        NvAPI_GPU_GetActiveOutputs  -  E3E89B6F
                    NvAPI_DRS_GetSettingNameFromId  -  D61CBE6E
         NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUFromUnAttachedDisplay  -  5018ED61
                 NvAPI_Mosaic_GetSupportedTopoInfo  -  FDB63C81
                                  NvAPI_GPU_GetIRQ  -  E4715417
                           NvAPI_GPU_GetOutputType  -  40A505E4
                            NvAPI_Stereo_IsEnabled  -  348FF8E1
                               NvAPI_Stereo_Enable  -  239C4545
                           NvAPI_GPU_GetSystemType  -  BAAABFCC
                                 NvAPI_GPU_SetEDID  -  E83D6456
               NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUsFromLogicalGPU  -  AEA3FA32
                               NvAPI_VIO_GetConfig  -  D34A789B
                   NvAPI_GetInterfaceVersionString  -  01053FA5
                       NvAPI_GPU_ResetECCErrorInfo  -  C02EEC20
                    NvAPI_SetCurrentMosaicTopology  -  D54B8989
              NvAPI_DISP_GetDisplayIdByDisplayName  -  AE457190
                                     NvAPI_GetView  -  D6B99D89
NvAPI_Stereo_DeleteConfigurationProfileRegistryKey  -  F117B834
                          NvAPI_DRS_DestroySession  -  DAD9CFF8
                 NvAPI_GPU_WorkstationFeatureQuery  -  004537DF
                           NvAPI_VIO_QueryTopology  -  869534E2
              NvAPI_DRS_EnumAvailableSettingValues  -  2EC39F90
                          NvAPI_DRS_GetBaseProfile  -  DA8466A0
                   NvAPI_OGL_ExpertModeDefaultsGet  -  AE921F12
                     NvAPI_DRS_DeleteApplicationEx  -  C5EA85A1
                       NvAPI_D3D1x_CreateSwapChain  -  1BC21B66
                  NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds  -  0078DBA2
                       NvAPI_DRS_FindProfileByName  -  7E4A9A0B
                     NvAPI_D3D9_UnregisterResource  -  BB2B17AA
                            NvAPI_DRS_EnumProfiles  -  BC371EE0
                             NvAPI_VIO_EnumDevices  -  FD7C5557
                           NvAPI_DRS_CreateProfile  -  CC176068
                          NvAPI_D3D9_StretchRectEx  -  22DE03AA
                              NvAPI_DRS_GetSetting  -  73BF8338
                       NvAPI_Stereo_InitActivation  -  C7177702
                     NvAPI_EnumNvidiaDisplayHandle  -  9ABDD40D
      NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedSLIOutputsWithLidState  -  96043CC7
                  NvAPI_Stereo_DecreaseConvergence  -  4C87E317
                              NvAPI_GPU_GetBusType  -  1BB18724
                   NvAPI_DRS_FindApplicationByName  -  EEE566B2
                                NvAPI_D3D9_ClearRT  -  332D3942
               NvAPI_GPU_GetVirtualFrameBufferSize  -  5A04B644
                        NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds  -  785210A2
                              NvAPI_DRS_SetSetting  -  577DD202
                       NvAPI_Stereo_GetConvergence  -  4AB00934
                        NvAPI_GPU_GetCurrentPstate  -  927DA4F6
                                  NvAPI_VIO_SetCSC  -  A1EC8D74
          NvAPI_CreateDisplayFromUnAttachedDisplay  -  63F9799E
                      NvAPI_DRS_SaveSettingsToFile  -  2BE25DF8
                           NvAPI_DRS_DeleteProfile  -  17093206
                   NvAPI_Stereo_Trigger_Activation  -  0D6C6CD2
                      NvAPI_GPU_GetThermalSettings  -  E3640A56
               NvAPI_Stereo_SetNotificationMessage  -  6B9B409E
             NvAPI_Stereo_CreateHandleFromIUnknown  -  AC7E37F4
                   NvAPI_Stereo_DecreaseSeparation  -  DA044458
               NvAPI_GPU_ValidateOutputCombination  -  34C9C2D4
             NvAPI_Stereo_ReverseStereoBlitControl  -  3CD58F89
                     NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedOutputs  -  1730BFC9
                    NvAPI_DRS_GetSettingIdFromName  -  CB7309CD
                            NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs  -  E5AC921F
                                  NvAPI_VIO_GetCSC  -  7B0D72A3
                        NvAPI_GPU_GetVbiosRevision  -  ACC3DA0A
               NvAPI_SYS_GetDriverAndBranchVersion  -  2926AAAD
                              NvAPI_SetDisplayPort  -  FA13E65A
              NvAPI_GPU_GetPhysicalFrameBufferSize  -  46FBEB03
                           NvAPI_DRS_CreateSession  -  0694D52E
                       NvAPI_VIO_EnumSignalFormats  -  EAD72FE4
                 NvAPI_GPU_GetECCConfigurationInfo  -  77A796F3
                     NvAPI_Mosaic_GetOverlapLimits  -  989685F0
                          NvAPI_GetHDMISupportInfo  -  6AE16EC3
                     NvAPI_Mosaic_EnumDisplayModes  -  78DB97D7
      NvAPI_Stereo_DeleteConfigurationProfileValue  -  49BCEECF
                           NvAPI_OGL_ExpertModeSet  -  3805EF7A
                  NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUsFromDisplay  -  34EF9506
      NvAPI_Mosaic_GetDisplayViewportsByResolution  -  DC6DC8D3
                                    NvAPI_VIO_Open  -  44EE4841
                            NvAPI_DRS_SaveSettings  -  FCBC7E14
                        NvAPI_D3D9_CreateSwapChain  -  1A131E09
                    NvAPI_GPU_GetHDCPSupportStatus  -  F089EEF5
NvAPI_DISP_GetAssociatedUnAttachedNvidiaDisplayHandle  -  A70503B2
                        NvAPI_Stereo_DestroyHandle  -  3A153134
                      NvAPI_DRS_RestoreAllDefaults  -  5927B094
                                NvAPI_VIO_SetGamma  -  964BF452
                            NvAPI_GPU_GetBoardInfo  -  22D54523
                          NvAPI_DRS_SetProfileInfo  -  16ABD3A9
                 NvAPI_DISP_GetGDIPrimaryDisplayId  -  1E9D8A31
                        NvAPI_Stereo_SetDriverMode  -  5E8F0BEC
                      NvAPI_D3D_GetCurrentSLIState  -  4B708B54
                                   NvAPI_SetViewEx  -  06B89E68
                                     NvAPI_I2CRead  -  2FDE12C5
                   NvAPI_DRS_RestoreProfileDefault  -  FA5F6134
                          NvAPI_GetDisplayPortInfo  -  C64FF367
                                   NvAPI_VIO_Start  -  CDE8E1A3
                           NvAPI_OGL_ExpertModeGet  -  22ED9516
           NvAPI_EnumNvidiaUnAttachedDisplayHandle  -  20DE9260
          NvAPI_SYS_GetGpuAndOutputIdFromDisplayId  -  112BA1A5
                           NvAPI_Stereo_Deactivate  -  2D68DE96
                             NvAPI_GPU_GetFullName  -  CEEE8E9F
                    NvAPI_DRS_DeleteProfileSetting  -  E4A26362
                   NvAPI_OGL_ExpertModeDefaultsSet  -  B47A657E
                             NvAPI_GetErrorMessage  -  6C2D048C
                      NvAPI_SetRefreshRateOverride  -  3092AC32
                   NvAPI_Stereo_IncreaseSeparation  -  C9A8ECEC
                         NvAPI_GPU_GetGpuCoreCount  -  C7026A87
          NvAPI_SYS_GetDisplayIdFromGpuAndOutputId  -  08F2BAB4
                         NvAPI_GPU_GetIllumination  -  9A1B9365
                                     NvAPI_SetView  -  0957D7B6
            NvAPI_GetAssociatedNvidiaDisplayHandle  -  35C29134
                                NvAPI_GPU_GetBusId  -  1BE0B8E5
                       NvAPI_DRS_DeleteApplication  -  2C694BC6
                         NvAPI_Stereo_SetActiveEye  -  96EEA9F8
                          NvAPI_GPU_GetAGPAperture  -  6E042794
                NvAPI_GetAssociatedDisplayOutputId  -  D995937E
                              NvAPI_EnableHWCursor  -  2863148D
                     NvAPI_Stereo_GetEyeSeparation  -  CE653127
                 NvAPI_DISP_GetMonitorCapabilities  -  3B05C7E1
                       NvAPI_Stereo_SetConvergence  -  3DD6B54B
                 NvAPI_GPU_WorkstationFeatureSetup  -  6C1F3FE4
         NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedOutputsWithLidState  -  CF8CAF39
                  NvAPI_Stereo_IncreaseConvergence  -  A17DAABE
                 NvAPI_GPU_GetDynamicPstatesInfoEx  -  60DED2ED
                   NvAPI_GPU_GetVbiosVersionString  -  A561FD7D
                     NvAPI_GPU_SetECCConfiguration  -  1CF639D9
                         NvAPI_VIO_EnumDataFormats  -  221FA8E8
```

the calling conventions can be found in the nvapi library reference

Hope this helps  ;)

Greetings, Nicki

Comment: Could you please explain how you used dumpbin to get the function names and their ID. Your answer is outdated and the API has probably changed since. Im currently trying dumpbin /exports nvapi.dll which isnt displaying what you got. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As I said, I disassembled it using **/DISASM** with dumpbin. In the result you can find calls to **nvapi_lpNvAPI_gpuQueryInterface** for each function that is exported by the NvApi. The only thing left to do is find the corresponding **push** operation preceding the **call** operation. The hex value pushed onto the call stack is the ID you want ;)

Answer (score 5):

I have cross-referenced part of NVIDIA's shipping drivers (nView.map) against nvapi.dll to come up with the following additional enumerants.

#### Some may be obsolete by now (this was from a 2009 driver release):

```
NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUFromDisplay                 1890E8DA
NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUFromGPUID                   5380AD1A
NvAPI_GetGPUIDfromPhysicalGPU                   6533EA3E
----
NvAPI_GetInfoFrameStatePvt                      7FC17574
NvAPI_GPU_GetMemoryInfo                         07F9B368
----
NvAPI_LoadMicrocode                             3119F36E
NvAPI_GetLoadedMicrocodePrograms                919B3136
NvAPI_GetDisplayDriverBuildTitle                7562E947
NvAPI_GetDisplayDriverCompileType               988AEA78
NvAPI_GetDisplayDriverSecurityLevel             9D772BBA
NvAPI_AccessDisplayDriverRegistry               F5579360
NvAPI_GetDisplayDriverRegistryPath              0E24CEEE
NvAPI_GetUnAttachedDisplayDriverRegistryPath    633252D8
NvAPI_GPU_GetRawFuseData                        E0B1DCE9
NvAPI_GPU_GetFoundry                            5D857A00
NvAPI_GPU_GetVPECount                           D8CBF37B
----
NvAPI_GPU_GetTargetID                           35B5FD2F
----
NvAPI_GPU_GetShortName                          D988F0F3
----
NvAPI_GPU_GetVbiosMxmVersion                    E1D5DABA 
NvAPI_GPU_GetVbiosImage                         FC13EE11
NvAPI_GPU_GetMXMBlock                           B7AB19B9
----
NvAPI_GPU_SetCurrentPCIEWidth                   3F28E1B9
NvAPI_GPU_SetCurrentPCIESpeed                   3BD32008
NvAPI_GPU_GetPCIEInfo                           E3795199
NvAPI_GPU_ClearPCIELinkErrorInfo                8456FF3D
NvAPI_GPU_ClearPCIELinkAERInfo                  521566BB
NvAPI_GPU_GetFrameBufferCalibrationLockFailures 524B9773
NvAPI_GPU_SetDisplayUnderflowMode               387B2E41
NvAPI_GPU_GetDisplayUnderflowStatus             ED9E8057
----
NvAPI_GPU_GetBarInfo                            E4B701E3
----
NvAPI_GPU_GetPSFloorSweepStatus                 DEE047AB
NvAPI_GPU_GetVSFloorSweepStatus                 D4F3944C
NvAPI_GPU_GetSerialNumber                       14B83A5F
NvAPI_GPU_GetManufacturingInfo                  A4218928
----
NvAPI_GPU_GetRamConfigStrap                     51CCDB2A
NvAPI_GPU_GetRamBusWidth                        7975C581
----
NvAPI_GPU_GetRamBankCount                       17073A3C
NvAPI_GPU_GetArchInfo                           D8265D24
NvAPI_GPU_GetExtendedMinorRevision              25F17421
NvAPI_GPU_GetSampleType                         32E1D697
NvAPI_GPU_GetHardwareQualType                   F91E777B
NvAPI_GPU_GetAllClocks                          1BD69F49
NvAPI_GPU_SetClocks                             6F151055
NvAPI_GPU_SetPerfHybridMode                     7BC207F8
NvAPI_GPU_GetPerfHybridMode                     5D7CCAEB
----
NvAPI_RestartDisplayDriver                      B4B26B65
NvAPI_GPU_GetAllGpusOnSameBoard                 4DB019E6
----
NvAPI_SetTopologyDisplayGPU                     F409D5E5
NvAPI_GetTopologyDisplayGPU                     813D89A8
NvAPI_SYS_GetSliApprovalCookie                  B539A26E
----
NvAPI_CreateUnAttachedDisplayFromDisplay        A0C72EE4
NvAPI_GetDriverModel                            25EEB2C4
NvAPI_GPU_CudaEnumComputeCapableGpus            5786CC6E
NvAPI_GPU_PhysxSetState                         4071B85E
NvAPI_GPU_PhysxQueryRecommendedState            7A4174F4
NvAPI_GPU_GetDeepIdleState                      1AAD16B4
NvAPI_GPU_SetDeepIdleState                      568A2292
----
NvAPI_GetScalingCaps                            8E875CF9
NvAPI_GPU_GetThermalTable                       C729203C
NvAPI_GPU_GetHybridControllerInfo               D26B8A58
NvAPI_SYS_SetPostOutput                         D3A092B1
```

*As a non-NDA developer I do not know any of the data structures or parameters to any of these functions, they are listed here only in the event that they prove useful to others as sergeyklenov's answer did for me.*

Answer (score 3):

A full list of memory addresses of the R375 x64 library is available here:

https://github.com/falahati/NvAPIWrapper/blob/master/NvAPIWrapper/Native/Helpers/FunctionId.cs

However, this is a big list and should not be posted here. But, to answer the real question, there is a script that gives you the same result using the `dumpbin` command:

https://github.com/falahati/NvAPIWrapper/blob/master/FunctionIdExtractor.ps1

You should be able to use this to get a list of all functions and their memory address.

```
$filename = "R375-developer\amd64\nvapi64.lib"
$dumpbinAddress = "$Env:VS140COMNTOOLS..\..\VC\bin\dumpbin.exe"
$dumpbinParameter = "/DISASM $filename"
Start-Process $dumpbinAddress $dumpbinParameter -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -RedirectStandardOutput "$filename.asm"
$content = Get-Content "$filename.asm"
$functionName = ""
foreach ($line in $content)
{
    if (!$line)
    {
        $functionName = ""
        continue;
    }
    if ($functionName -eq "" -and $line.EndsWith(":") -and ($line.StartsWith("NvAPI_") -or $line.StartsWith("?Module_InitializeHelper")))
    {
        $functionName = $line.TrimEnd(':')
        if ($functionName.StartsWith("?Module_InitializeHelper"))
        {
            $functionName = "NvAPI_Initialize"
        }
        continue;
    }
    $leadingPattern = "ecx,"
    if ($functionName -ne "" -and $line.Contains($leadingPattern) -and $line.EndsWith("h"))
    {
        $functionAddress = $line.Substring($line.IndexOf($leadingPattern) + $leadingPattern.Length).TrimEnd('h')
        $functionAddressNumberic = 0
        if ([int32]::TryParse($functionAddress, 
            [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::HexNumber, 
            [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture, 
            [ref] $functionAddressNumberic))
        {
            $functionAddress = $functionAddressNumberic.ToString("X")
            Write-Host "$functionName = 0x$functionAddress,"
            $functionName = ""
            continue;
        }
    }
}
Remove-Item "$filename.asm"
```